# RecyclerView получить текст из айтема по position

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Как можно получить в Активити текст из элемента в RecyclerView по позиции, там в айтемах только текст и размер Recycler всегда одинаковый. Это не по нажатию нужно, а просто строчкой желательно

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Изначально не очень понятно как именно вы сетите данные в адаптер (что именно передаёте), так же не очень понятно какой именно вам нужен язык (`Java/Kotlin`).

Допустим вы передаёте в адаптер массив, тогда можно сделать так:

```
val array = (recyclerView.adapter as YouAdapterClass).yourArray
```

---

```
if (recyclerView.getAdapter() instanceOf YouAdapterClass){
    ArrayList<String> items = (YouAdapterClass) recyclerView.getAdapter().getYourArray();
}
```

дальше уже по индексу получаете то что вам нужно. Так же стоит добавить проверку что этот массив не пустой. Как-то так по логике должно быть.